# where is my code error using urlfetch on google app engine 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

this is my code:

```
class save(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        counter = Counter.get_by_key_name('aa-s')
        counter.count += 1
        url = "http://www.google.com"
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)

        if result.status_code == 200:
            counter.ajax = result.content
            counter.put()

        self.redirect('/')
```

and the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 511, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "F:\ss\Task Queue\main.py", line 48, in get
    counter.ajax = result.content
  File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 542, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 2453, in validate
    raise BadValueError('Property %s is not multi-line' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property ajax is not multi-line
INFO     2010-11-04 08:24:29,905 dev_appserver.py:3283] "GET /save HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

so i cant find the error ,

did you  .

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to store the result into counter.ajax, which is a StringProperty that does not have multiline=True. Either set multiline=True in the definition of 'ajax', or replace it with a TextProperty(). The latter is almost certainly the correct answer - TextProperties can be longer, and aren't indexed.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in your Counter model.

"ajax" needs to be a multiline string property.  See the [Types and Property Classes documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#StringProperty).

You'll want to do:

```
ajax = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
```

Also note that db.StringProperty can only be used for strings of 500 characters or less.